# how to execute a job at a certain time in a different timezone

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

Say if i am in BST i.e British Summer Time and i want to execute a job at 19.30 as per the US/Eastern timezone, then how could i acheive it.

Sample code that i tried,

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
LocalDateTime localTimeNow = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(now, ZoneOffset.systemDefault());
//if BST then use "Europe/London" 
//if US/Eastern then use "America/New_York" 
// For EST also use "America/New_York"
// If GB-Eire then use "Europe/London"
ZonedDateTime bsTime = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));

ZonedDateTime nyAmerica = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));

// Lets calculate the difference between 2 timezones
// Between London and EST
long timeDiff = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(bsTime, nyAmerica);
System.out.println("timeDiff - " + timeDiff);

int minutes = (int) ((timeDiff / 1000) / 60);

System.out.println("Time diff bet London and EST - " + minutes + " minutes");

long diff = Duration.between(bsTime, nyAmerica).getSeconds();
int mins = (int) (diff / 60);
System.out.println("Time diff bet London and EST - " + mins + " minutes");
```

It is giving me Zero in both cases.

What i want is that i have to use this delay to pass it to the executor service as below,

```
executor.schedule(myRunnable, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

So even though i am in Britain, the job should get executed at at 19.30 as per the US/Eastern.

Also some of the abbreviations like EST, BST are not a valid ZoneId.
So how could i handle those cases when i have timezone in an abbreviated format like EST or BST etc. ?

Comment: You cannot use `LocalDateTime` to track a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***UPDATE:** Original answer below shows how to calculate local time to start a job that must run at a certain time of day in a different time zone.*

If you just want to calculate how long to wait until that time, it can be done much easier, without involving the local time zone.

```java
LocalTime jobStartTime = LocalTime.of(19, 30);
ZoneId jobZone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");

ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(jobZone);
ZonedDateTime jobDateTime = now.with(jobStartTime);
if (jobDateTime.isBefore(now))
    jobDateTime.plusDays(1);
long delay = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(now, jobDateTime);

System.out.println("now         = " + now);
System.out.println("jobDateTime = " + jobDateTime);
System.out.println("delay       = " + delay + "  =  " + Duration.ofMillis(delay));
```

*Output*

```
now         = 2020-07-17T08:18:45.482028800-04:00[America/New_York]
jobDateTime = 2020-07-17T19:30-04:00[America/New_York]
delay       = 40274517  =  PT11H11M14.517S
```

---

#### Original Answer

`now` is `2020-07-17 07:57:45 Z`
In London that is `2020-07-17 08:57:45 +01:00`
In New York that is `2020-07-17 03:57:45 -04:00`.

What is the time different between London and New York?
**0 seconds**, because they are the **same time**.

The code in the question doesn't calculate when the time will be 19:30. Instead, it attempts to calculates the time zone difference as of *right now*, but because of Daylight Savings Time, the time zone difference at 7:30 PM might be *different*, so the approach is wrong.

If you are in London, and need to know when it will next be 19:30 in New York, do it like this:

```java
Instant now = Instant.now();
ZoneId localZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
ZoneId remoteZone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
System.out.println("now             = " + now);

ZonedDateTime remoteNow = now.atZone(remoteZone);
LocalDate remoteDate = remoteNow.toLocalDate();
LocalTime remoteTime = LocalTime.of(19, 30);
if (remoteNow.toLocalTime().isAfter(remoteTime))
    remoteDate = remoteDate.plusDays(1);
ZonedDateTime remoteStartTime = ZonedDateTime.of(remoteDate, remoteTime, remoteZone);
System.out.println("remoteNow       = " + remoteNow);
System.out.println("remoteStartTime = " + remoteStartTime);

ZonedDateTime localStartTime = remoteStartTime.withZoneSameInstant(localZone);
System.out.println("localNow        = " + now.atZone(localZone));
System.out.println("localStartTime  = " + localStartTime);
```

*Output*

```
now             = 2020-07-17T07:57:45.206007800Z
remoteNow       = 2020-07-17T03:57:45.206007800-04:00[America/New_York]
remoteStartTime = 2020-07-17T19:30-04:00[America/New_York]
localNow        = 2020-07-17T08:57:45.206007800+01:00[Europe/London]
localStartTime  = 2020-07-18T00:30+01:00[Europe/London]
```

So, on a computer running British time zone, the next 7:30 PM time in Eastern US is at half past midnight tonight.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just what i needed.  @Andreas                                                  
 //localStartTime is the time when the job should get executed.
  long timeDiff = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(localNow, localStartTime);
  System.out.println("delay - " + timeDiff);
  System.out.println("Delay in minutes - " + ((timeDiff / 1000) / 60) + " minutes"); Now i could pass the delay to the executor as, executor.schedule(myRunnable, timeDiff,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use Spring Boot Quartz Scheduler
Reference: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-quartz-scheduler-email-scheduling-example/

Comment: Not useful, since the question doesn't say anything about using Quartz, or even Spring Boot.